# Android FCM Notification Cannot Be Clicked Second Time

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I Have problem with my notification.

First way - I open my app, then I push notification from FCM first time, I click the notif, my code executed, I push again for second time, I click my notif, my code still execute, I try more more time is worked well.

Second way - My app still close, I push notif from FCM first time, then I Click the notif, so my app will open and my code executed, then I push notif again for second time, my code NOT executed, I try more more time still NOT working.

until I swipe my app, and try again, the problem still happen.

this is my code

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    var userInformation = AccountTableDao()
    val sp: SharedPreferences by lazy { SharedPreference.instance }
    val gad: GetAccountData by lazy { AccountDatabase.instance }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)
        Log.d("firebase", "INSTANCE ID ===> $token")
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        remoteMessage?.let {
            sendNotification(it.data)
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(messageData: Map<String, String>) {

        var status = messageData.get("status")
        val uuid = messageData.get("uuid")
        val restaurantId = messageData.get("restaurantId")

        val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val titleText = messageData.get("title").toString()
        val contentText = messageData.get("body").toString()

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, RestaurantMenuActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Argument.NOTIF_UUID, uuid)
        intent.putExtra(Argument.NOTIF_RESTAURANT_ID, restaurantId)
        intent.putExtra(Argument.NOTIF_STATUS, status)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext,System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel("appety", "appety_notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)

            notificationManager .createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            notificationManager.notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
            .setChannelId(System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
            .setContentTitle(titleText)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText))
            .setContentText(contentText)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp)
            .setLargeIcon( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.logo_appety))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(false)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorBonAppety))
            .build())
        }
        else{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                notificationManager .notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), NotificationCompat.Builder(this, System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
                .setContentTitle(titleText)
                .setStyle (NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText))
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp)
                .setLargeIcon( BitmapFactory.decodeResource(applicationContext.resources, R.drawable.logo_appety))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorBonAppety))
                .build())
            } else {
                notificationManager .notify(System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "1")
                .setContentTitle(titleText)
                .setStyle (NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentText))
                .setContentText(contentText)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .build())
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = "token"
    }
}
```

and manifest

```
<service
        android:name=".service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Why `Pending Intent` not working and how to fix that.
Sorry for my english and regard.

Comment: Try adding PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT|PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. For request code, I believe you should do something like this (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % Integer.MAX_VALUE) instead of using System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(). Int has minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: I got still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should try setAutoCancel() method when creating the notification.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
NotificationCompat.Builder summary = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
summary.setAutoCancel(true);
```

And if you passing an intent to the notification, then use this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: I think i had set setAutoCancel() into true

Comment: If you set `setAutoCancel(true)` then the notification will dissappear from the notification tray after you tap on it. If it's not working then try other options of PendingIntent attributes like follows
`PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)`